# Pandas Slice Columns and select subsets based on between condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe as follows:

```
                    100     105   110
timestamp                        
2020-11-0112:00:00   0.2    0.5    0.1
2020-11-0112:01:00   0.3    0.8    0.2
2020-11-0112:02:00   0.8    0.9    0.4
2020-11-0112:03:00   1      0      0.4
2020-11-0112:04:00   0      1      0.5
2020-11-0112:05:00   0.5    1      0.2
```

I want to select columns with dataframe where the values would be greater than equal 0.5 and less than equal to 1,  and I want the index/timestamp in which these occurrences happened. Each column could have multiple such occurrences. So, 100, can be between 0.5 and 1 from 12:00 to 12:03 and then again from 12:20 to 12:30. It needs to reset when it hits 0. The column names are variable.

I also want the time difference in which the column value was between 0.5 and 1, so from the above it was 3 minutes, and 10 minutes.

The expected output would be with a dict for ranges the indexes appeared in:

```
                    100     105   110
timestamp                        
2020-11-0112:00:00   NaN    0.5    NaN
2020-11-0112:01:00   NaN    0.8    NaN
2020-11-0112:02:00   0.8    0.9    NaN
2020-11-0112:03:00   1      NaN    NaN
2020-11-0112:04:00   NaN     1     0.5
2020-11-0112:05:00   0.5     1     NaN
```

and probably a way to calculate the minutes which could be in a dict/list of dicts:

```
["105":
[{"from": "2020-11-0112:00:00", "to":"2020-11-0112:02:00"}, 
{"from": "2020-11-0112:04:00", "to":"2020-11-0112:05:00"}]
...
]
```

Essentially I want a the dicts at the end to evaluate.

Comment: show us the output that you want

Comment: Updated question to include expected output

Comment: For now, the question contains a multistep task. Is the problem in Pandas sequence or timestamp comparison? If only Pandas slicing is the problem, please take a look at my answer. If timestamps are the problem too, that should be a separate question.

Comment: timestamps are always in sequence. that's not a problem. There could be missing timestamps but it would still be in ascending order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, it would be best if you got the ordered sequence of timestamps; then, you can manipulate it to get the differences. If the question is only about Pandas slicing and not about timestamp operations, then you need to do the following operation:

```
df[df["100"] >= 0.5][df["100"] <= 1]["timestamp"].values
```

#### Pandas data frames comparaision operations

For Pandas, data frames, normal comparison operations are overridden. If you do `dataframe_instance >= 0.5`, the result is a sequence of boolean values. An individual value in the sequence results from comparing an individual data frame value to `0.5`.

#### Pandas data frame slicing

This sequence could be used to filter a subsequence from your data frame. It is possible because Pandas slicing is overridden and implemented as a reach filtering algorithm.

Comment: The dataframe would always be ordered by timestamp ascending. The challenge is I can't do it on individual columns as they are variable and get added to the dataframe dynamically. So I want something which does it on all existing columns.

Comment: So, you don't know the names of your columns. Is it correct?

Comment: Yes. It could be 5 columns at 12:00 and then one more column gets added on the next.

Comment: I'd rather get column names from a data frame then do the same as I did in the answer with already known columns. I don't know a way to do column operations, not knowing the names.

Comment: okay, if I do loop through, 5k+ columns and 10k+ rows it's going to take a crazy amount of time I suppose.

Comment: If you have 5k+ columns and want to do an operation for each, it will take a crazy amount of time anyway.

Comment: You can do https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html `apply` using `axis=1` to apply the operation to each column, but a crazy amount of time is guaranteed.

Comment: alright, I tried running the above on some columns: 
UserWarning: Boolean Series key will be reindexed to match DataFrame index.

Comment: Sounds expected :)

Comment: One final thing, would it detect multiple instances of values going between 0.5 and 1?

Comment: Of course, I explained in the answer how it happens.